# Installing SymmetricDS service

Tags: windows, windows-services, symmetricds

I have 2 machines. M1 is installed SymmetricDS on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Webstercare\MyFolder\Tools\Synchronisation". I shared this folder to everyone with full permission.

In M2 I map network drive the folder as a drive.
I run InstallSymmetricDS.bat then SymmetricDS is installed in M2 as well. But I can't start the service.
Can everyone tell me how to start the service? I would like to use as the same folder for as the same configuration. So I just edit one time for both M1 and M2.
In Regedit:

ImagePath: "java" -Djava.io.tmpdir="Z:\tmp" -jar "Z:\lib\symmetric-wrapper.jar" init "Z:\conf\sym_service.conf"

I also installed Java 32 bit.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the service control manager running as SYSTEM is going to see Z:\ as a valid path.  It's just not possible what you are trying to do.  You would need to mount the file system at a much lower level (like what a SAN and Windows Clustering does) so that each windows machine see's it as a local disk.

Comment: Could you tell me how to mount the file system at a much lower level (like what a SAN and Windows Clustering does)?

Comment: That would be a question for over at ServerFault.com